# How To SetUp Multi node Cluster in my own server?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cluster

How To SetUp Multi node Cluster in my own server ?

I have already use Minikube,kind but i need to setup multinode cluster in my own server without using Google Cloud, AWS and Red Hat OpenShift.

**Can anyone provide me any documentation or tutorial.**

Comment: Maybe [kubespray](https://kubespray.io/#/) can help. It provides an ansible playbook that with correct inventory file can configure multi-node clusters.

Comment: Can you share any doc or tutorial to deploy a spring boot application to multinode cluster using kubespray

Comment: kubespray is used to configure the cluster itself, deployment of an application is another story, once you have a configured cluster you can continue with deployment of your application

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow this article: https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/15/kubernetes-setup-using-ansible-and-vagrant/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using kubeadm, please check-out below mention doc

Click [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/high-availability/)